# Why is apache mod_rewrite not routing /index correctly?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Works fine:

- When going to `/index.php` the site home page loads
- When going to `/sdagkljahsdf/sdfsafdsaf/` the site (framework) 404
  loads through `index.php`

Works incorrectly:

- When going to `/index` the apache error message comes with a `Not
  Found`: `The requested URL /index was not found on this server.`

So using apaches `404` not routing through the framework `index.php`

I want it to route through `index.php`

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV []
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors off

#hide index.php
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Turn on the engine
RewriteEngine on
#Don't Perform for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Exerything else redirect to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</ifModule>
Redirect 301 /donate /funding
Redirect 301 /site/donate /funding
```

Here is my `vhost`:

```
<Directory {{ www_path }}>
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules ?

Comment: @starkeen that's it, apart from some `php_flag`s and some `301 redirect`s

Comment: Can you post your complete htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen I've updated it